# I'm having trouble with my attempt of objective-c block equivalent in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

Here is the objective-c code:

```
options.onPan = ^(MDCPanState *state){
    if (state.thresholdRatio == 1.f && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Let go now to delete the photo!");
    }
};
```

Swift:

```
   var options = MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions()
        options.delegate = self
        options.likedText = "Keep"
        options.likedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        options.nopeText = "Delete"

        options.onPan = { (state: MDCPanState) in
            if state.thresholdRatio == 1.0 && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirection.Left {
                println("Let go now to delete the photo!");
            }
        }
```

This is throwing an error:

'(MDCPanState) -> (MDCPanState) -> $T2' is not convertible to 'MDCPanState'

Would appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: What is the type declaration of `options.onPan`?  The implication of the error message seems to be that the closure needs to return non void.

Comment: Also, is there an `=` sign missing in the Swift example?

Comment: @JeremyP I've updated my answer. The return type is MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% since I don't have XCode near me at the moment, but I believe you need to change this:

```
options.onPan = { (state: MDCPanState) in
        if state.thresholdRatio == 1.0 && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirection.Left {
            println("Let go now to delete the photo!");
        }
```

to this:

```
options.onPan = { (state: MDCPanState!) -> Void in
        if state.thresholdRatio == 1.0 && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirection.Left {
            println("Let go now to delete the photo!");
        }
```

Comment: What's weird about the syntax to you?

Comment: Its seeing the { after the equals sign.  I haven't seen this construct before. Can you provide more information or a link to some docs to help understand it? Is it shortened notation?

Comment: you are setting onPan to a completion block and that's the syntax in swift.  this may help https://www.codefellows.org/blog/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift